# how to create new table in power bi depended on Max date from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In powerbi I have **table42** with 3 columns ( productId , amount , date)
i need to creat a new table depends on this table(table42) with filter return only max date for each product and amount so i can calaculate the total amount

below my condation in sql

```
case when d.Date=(SELECT max(z.Date) FROM table42 zz WHERE d.prdAcctId=zz.prdAcctId)
```

I tried this but I don't get any result

```
= #table({"prdAcctId","date", "amount"},{table42[prdAcctId],table42[date],DATEVALUE(MAX('Table42'[DATE]))}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
= FILTER(
     table42
    ,[date]=CALCULATE(MAX(table42[date]),ALLEXCEPT(table42,table42[prdAcctId]))
    
  )
```

Comment: Thank you , but it return all days not only max date ..

Comment: try altered measure